# Решить проблему со скриптом в JavaScript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть скрипт:

```
var checkedItem = [];
    $(".block-insideBlock .user").on("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("checked-item");
        checkedItem.push($(this).text());
    })
```

При нажатии на тег с классом `.user` (Как показано в скрипте), к тегу прибавляется класс `checked-item` и в массив `checkedItem[]` добавляется текст из тега, при вторичном нажатии класс `checked-item` удаляется, а вот текст в массиве нет. Вопрос в том как сделать так, чтобы при вторичном нажатии помимо класса исчезал и текст из массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".block-insideBlock .user").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("checked-item");

    checkedItem.length = 0;
    $(".block-insideBlock .user.checked-item").each(function() {
      checkedItem.push($(this).text());
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо либо перестраивать массив полностью заново при любом изменении, либо где-то хранить информацию, связывающую элементы массива с DOM-элементами.

Например, можно заменить массив на объект и использовать индексы .user(работает только если все рядом в DOM) и ключи объекта:

```
var checkedItem = {};
$(".block-insideBlock .user").on("click", function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("checked-item");
    var key = 'user_'+$(this).index(); // вычисляем идентифицирующий текущий блок ключ
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked-item')) {
      checkedItem[key] = $(this).text();
    } else {
      delete checkedItem[key];
    }
})
```